# Setting alarm at different timings using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am currently developing an application that will set off a alarm at some timings. Now I have managed to set it off after 10 seconds however I don't know how to set alarm in the format that is same as the built-in alarm system where they set like 10 minutes before the event or 1 day before the event, etc.

Comment: Please don't use pseudo-tags in the question title. That's what (proper) tags are for. If you feel such a strong need, construct a proper statement or question that actually integrates the word(s) instead of just tacking them on.

Comment: The thing you are looking for is Calendar Events, not Alarm.

Comment: Oh I didn't know which is which so I put it as alarm. Anyways, do you happen to know how can I set the alarm?